# Change the timeout after a spoken keyword with Cognitive Services

Tags: c#, .net, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, speech

I want to create a type of voice actuated personal assistant similar to Siri or Alexa. Say a keyword and then process the rest of the audio to text. I have a working version where I can do just that. But if you say the keyword and wait just a moment too long it times out. I'm unable to say the keyword, wait 1 or 2 seconds and then say the rest of the command.

I want to be able to say the keyword and have it wait for 10 or 15 seconds before it actually times out.

I've tried setting these properties but it didn't change anything.

```
SpeechConfig.SetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_InitialSilenceTimeoutMs, "15000");
SpeechConfig.SetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_EndSilenceTimeoutMs, "15000");
```

and

```
SpeechRecognizer.Properties.SetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_InitialSilenceTimeoutMs, "15000");
SpeechRecognizer.Properties.SetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_EndSilenceTimeoutMs, "15000");
```

I'm using

```
SpeechRecognizer.StartKeywordRecognitionAsync()
```

to do the recognizing. I tried to stop it with

```
SpeedRecognizer.StopKeywordRecognitionAsync()
```

and then use

```
SpeechRecognizer.StartContinousRecognitionAsync()
```

in either of the SessionStarted, SessionStopped, Recognizing or Recognized events. The Canceled event never gets called.

I was expecting that it would wait after the keyword was spoken but it didn't. Does anyone know how to do this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by going through the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/

The basic premise is to create a KeywordRecognizer first. Then call the recognizer function to get the keyword. The result with be a RecognizedKeyword and from there you can create a SpeechRecognizer. Call the recognizer function and you'll get the rest of the command. The default delay is 30 seconds after it get the keyword until it times out.

Here's some code to give an example:

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
    using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
    
    namespace SpeechRecognitionDemo
    {
        class Program
        {
            static SpeechConfig speechConfig;
            static KeywordRecognitionModel keywordModel;
            static AudioConfig audioConfig;
            static TaskCompletionSource<int> stopRecognition;
    
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
                // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
                speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("subscription key", "region");
                speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
    
                // set this property to allow more time between words in the command
                speechConfig.SetProperty(PropertyId.Speech_SegmentationSilenceTimeoutMs, "2000");
    
                // Creates an instance of a keyword recognition model. Update this to
                // point to the location of your keyword recognition model.
                keywordModel = KeywordRecognitionModel.FromFile("keywords.table");
                audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
    
                await RunAssistant();
            }
    
            static async Task RunAssistant()
            {
                bool keepRunning = true;
    
                while (keepRunning)
                {
                    // Starts recognizing.
                    Console.WriteLine($"Say something starting with the keyword 'Hey Assistant' followed by whatever you want...");
    
                    stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    
                    using (var keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(audioConfig))
                    {
                        // recognize the keywords
                        KeywordRecognitionResult result = await keywordRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync(keywordModel);
    
                        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedKeyword)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED KEYWORD: Text={result.Text}");
    
                            using (var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig))
                            {
                                // Subscribes to events.
                                speechRecognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
                                {
                                    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                                    }
                                };
    
                                speechRecognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
                                {
                                    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                                    }
                                    else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                                    }
                                };
    
                                speechRecognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("\nSession started event.\n");
                                };
    
                                speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("\nSession stopped event.");
                                    Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
    
                                    stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                                };

                                // now recognize the commands
                                await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
                            }
                        }
    
                        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELLED KEYWORD");
                            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                        }
    
                        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"NO MATCH KEYWORD");
                        }
    
                        // Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
                        Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });
    
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                    }
                }
                audioConfig.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll need to create a keywords.table file using Speech Studio, which is pretty self-explanatory. You'll also need a subscription id and then download a model to use offline.

This example waits for a keyword, then waits for more text. It prints the results to the console and then comes back around to do it all over again.